# RUNNABLE Thread may not consume CPU when in native method?

Tags: java, performance, thread-dump

When taking a threaddump of a Tomcat server that is mostly idling, a lot of Threads may show up in state RUNNABLE like this:

```
"http-bio-8443-exec-21975" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f6f6406c000 nid=0x222a runnable [0x00007f6f156ae000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:516)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:501)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.setRequestLineReadTimeout(Http11Processor.java:173)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:924)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
        - locked <0x00000007cadcd3f8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

My interpretation of the sourcecode is that this Thread is waiting (with timeout) on more data from an HTTP keepalive connection. So even though the Thread is RUNNABLE, it doesn't consume CPU.

[Thread.State RUNNABLE javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#RUNNABLE) says:

> A thread in the runnable state is executing in the Java virtual machine but it may be waiting for other resources from the operating system such as processor.

So in this case, that other resource would be I/O instead of CPU.

In other question [Java socketRead0 Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12546260/1245428), [Geoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1691270/geoff) answers:

> I believe that when you are in a Java native method, the stack trace will say RUNNABLE even if the call is actually blocked waiting for some event. In essence, I don't believe Java has any way of knowing what a native method is actually doing, so it flags these calls as RUNNABLE. I have seen this with socketRead0() and socketAccept() -- both of which typically block.

I came to similar conclusions, and I would like to verify this interpretation in this dedicated question, which is:

**If I want to analyze CPU consumption by looking at RUNNABLE Threads, I may have to rule out Threads in Native Methods by very closely looking at their sourcecode?**

The point is that it's not as easy as looking at the Thread's state only, but rather having to delve into sourcecode and starting to guess what a particular native method may be doing (or even looking into its C or C++ sourcecode).

Answer (score 1):

On the lines of [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), my answer would be yes, that may be necessary, and it may be useful to have a little compendium of native methods encountered so far.

Comment: I think you already answer to your own question. The title is not completly true: a native method consumes CPU. But, as you explained, the JVM don't know what is doing a native method, so the status "RUNNABLE" is not relevant, the thread **can** be waiting for IO for example (and so not waiting for CPU). Obviously you can use OS monitoring tools, but I won't get a pretty Java Stack Trace...

Answer (score 0):

> If I want to analyze CPU consumption by looking at RUNNABLE Threads, I may have to rule out Threads in Native Methods by very closely looking at their sourcecode?

You may *want to* rule them out.  But in general, you can't.  A native method could alternate between two states in which it is either blocked or consuming large amounts of CPU.  Even if you examined the code in detail, you would not be able to tell which state it was in from just the thread stack dump.

(If you could get hold of the native PC, you might be able to ... but even that would take a heroic effort to implement.)

---

Of course, there are lots of native methods in the standard libraries that consume next to no CPU, and you could certainly make use of that in your analysis.  However, there are other standard native libraries that are likely to exhibit "mixed mode" behaviour; e.g. the native ZIP libraries and some of the native libraries used in AWT, SWT and so on.