# Getting stuck at SocketInputStream.socketRead0

Tags: java, sockets, apache-commons-httpclient

I have the project, in which I download many pages simultaneosly in many tasks, which are processed via `ThreadPool` (size = 200). All this tasks are using the same method `getPage` for downloading the page (with Apache Commons HttpClient and Apache Commons IO):

```
public static String getPage(String url)
        throws IOException {

    HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);

    HttpResponse response = HTTP_CLIENT_BUILDER.build().execute(request);
    try (InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent()) {
        return IOUtils.toString(content, "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

while `HTTP_CLIENT_BUILDER` is a static field initialized this way:

```
 private static final HttpClientBuilder HTTP_CLIENT_BUILDER = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                .setSocketTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS) // 60_000
                .setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS) // 5_000
                .build());
```

**Problem statement**: at some moment (when most of the tasks are finished) all the remaining threads are getting stuck at the native method `SocketInputStream.socketRead0`, so `jdb` is saying, that they're all running (hmm, yeah, I expect that behavior with native method running :-) ):

```
> threads
Group system:
  (java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler)0xac4 Reference Handler cond. waiting
  (java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread)0xac5  Finalizer         cond. waiting
  (java.lang.Thread)0xac6                         Signal Dispatcher running
  (java.lang.Thread)0xac7                         Java2D Disposer   cond. waiting
Group main:
  (java.lang.Thread)0xac9                         pool-1-thread-5   running
  (java.lang.Thread)0xaca                         pool-1-thread-12  running
  (... 12 more threads from ThreadPool ...)
  (java.lang.Thread)0xad7                         DestroyJavaVM     running
> where 0xac9
  [1] java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0 (native method)
  [2] java.net.SocketInputStream.read (SocketInputStream.java:150)
  [3] java.net.SocketInputStream.read (SocketInputStream.java:121)
  [4] sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully (InputRecord.java:465)
  [5] sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read (InputRecord.java:503)
  [6] sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord (SSLSocketImpl.java:961)
  [7] sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:1,363)
  [8] sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:1,391)
  [9] sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:1,375)
  [10] org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket (SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:275)
  [11] org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket (SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:254)
  [12] org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect (HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:117)
  [13] org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:314)
  [14] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute (MainClientExec.java:363)
  [15] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute (MainClientExec.java:219)
  [16] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute (ProtocolExec.java:195)
  [17] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute (RetryExec.java:86)
  [18] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute (RedirectExec.java:108)
  [19] org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute (InternalHttpClient.java:186)
  [20] org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
  [21] org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
  [22] <package>.Utils.getPage (Utils.java:122)
  [23...] <internal details>
> # the same picture for all of them
```

I don't understand, why this can happen, but I've found [Java bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8049846), which is maybe related to the issue. So maybe I'm not looking for real solution, but for some workaround.

Since the bug is filed against Linux, I should say, that I'm also using virtual machine running Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64

**UPD**: OK, what I've tried now is adding new timeout with `setConnectionRequestTimeout` (just to make sure, it doesn't work) add `finally` block withing `getPage`:

```
...
try (InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent()) {
    return IOUtils.toString(content, "UTF-8");
} finally {
   httpClient.getConnectionManager().closeIdleConnections(0, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
}
```

Let's see, if this helps.

**UPD2**: this seems to help a little bit, but still, I have this permanentry running tasks getting stuck approximately once a day.

Comment: Thread which doing `Socket.read` will shown up as `Runnable`, see this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544212. Most probably, remote side keeps their end of socket open, that's why your tasks can't finish. E.g., you've submitted more tasks to an Executor than needed to download remote resources, and the idle rest of tasks is left waiting.

Comment: @VictorSorokin that shouldn't happen as I've set timeouts (see initializer for `HTTP_CLIENT_BUILDER`)

Comment: Yes, overlooked, sorry. Then I'd examine connection with tcpdump or similar to understand what keeps TCP connection alive. Perhaps, server-side logs can be handy too.

Comment: Then, once you know (somehow) that all is downloaded, close opened sockets on your side. This will free pool threads and stuck tasks will be cancelled (w/ an exception). This implies you need to put opened sockets in some shared collection inside `getPage`, which should be made available for cancellation task.

Comment: @VictorSorokin The sockets themselves are the implementation details under HttpClient's hood, so I'm not sure, how can I get them. Also, it seems to me a big overkill to create such a collection.

Comment: This is a very common issue and I'm baffled how it's still not fixed by Apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I've failed to find any simple workaround (or the real solution), so I've manager to write my own workaround, I hope it'll help someone with that error:

Create class `ConnectionSupervisor`:

```
private static class ConnectionsSupervisor extends Thread {
    private Set<RequestEntry> streams = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();

    public ConnectionsSupervisor() {
        setDaemon(true);
        setName("Connections supervisor");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(CONNECTIONS_SUPERVISOR_WAIT_MS);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            }
            long time = timestamp();
            streams.stream().filter(entry -> time > entry.timeoutBorder).forEach(entry -> {
                HttpUriRequest request = entry.request;
                System.err.format("HttpUriRequest killed after timeout (%d sec.) exceeded: %s%n",
                        FULL_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_S,
                        request);
                request.abort();
            });
        }
    }

    public void addRequest(HttpUriRequest request) {
        streams.add(new RequestEntry(timestamp() + FULL_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_S, request));
    }

    public void removeRequest(HttpUriRequest request) {
        streams.removeIf(entry -> entry.request == request);
    }

    private static class RequestEntry {
        private long timeoutBorder;
        private HttpUriRequest request;

        public RequestEntry(long timeoutBorder, HttpUriRequest request) {
            this.timeoutBorder = timeoutBorder;
            this.request = request;
        }
    }
}


public static long timestamp() {
    return Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
}
```

Somewhere there should be an instance of `ConnectionSupervisor`, something like:

```
private static final ConnectionsSupervisor connectionsSupervisor = new ConnectionsSupervisor();
static {
    connectionsSupervisor.start();
}
```

In something like `getPage` method:

```
HttpUriRequest request = ...;

// ...

connectionsSupervisor.addRequest(request);

try (InputStream content = httpClient.execute(request).getEntity().getContent()) {
    return IOUtils.toString(content, "UTF-8");
    // or any other usage
} finally {
    connectionsSupervisor.removeRequest(request);
    // highly important!
}
```